How to correctly redirect logs from ECS fargate to fluentbit?
I have an ECS container with the following tasks: an application, the OpenTelemetry Collector, and Fluent Bit. I'm facing an issue with the application logs, which are currently being recorded as stdout. Previously, I used Datadog, and the logs were pushed correctly. Now, I want to change the configuration so that the logs go to the OpenTelemetry Collector and from there to ClickHouse. However, it seems that the logs are not being passed to Fluent Bit.
Could you help me identify any potential mistakes in the configuration?
My fluent-bit.conf
[SERVICE]
    Flush               5
    Log_Level           info
    Daemon              off

[INPUT]
    Name                forward
    Listen              0.0.0.0
    Port                24224
    Buffer_Chunk_Size   1M
    Buffer_Max_Size     10M
    Tag_Prefix          ecs.


[FILTER]
    Name         parser
    Match        *
    Key_Name     log
    Parser       json
    Reserve_Data True

[OUTPUT]
    Name          forward
    Match         *
    Host          localhost
    Port          24284 (otel collector task)

[OUTPUT]
    Name  stdout
    Match *

I tried with
[INPUT]
    Name   dummy
    Dummy {"message": "custom dummy"}

and it's worked
My otel-config
receivers:
  prometheus:
    config:
      scrape_configs:
        - job_name: '${JOB_NAME}'
          static_configs:
            - targets: ['localhost:9394']
          relabel_configs:
            - source_labels: [__address__]
              regex: (.*)
              target_label: instance_ip
              replacement: "$1"
            - source_labels: [job]
              target_label: job_name
              replacement: '${JOB_NAME}'

        - job_name: opentelemetry-collector
          scrape_interval: 30s
          static_configs:
          - targets:
            - 127.0.0.1:8888
                  
  fluentforward/tcp:
    endpoint: 0.0.0.0:24284
  awsecscontainermetrics:
    collection_interval: 10s
    
  otlp:
    protocols:
      http:
        endpoint: "0.0.0.0:4318"
      grpc:
        endpoint: "0.0.0.0:4317"
        
processors:
  transform/firelens:
    log_statements:
      - context: log
        statements:
          # parse json logs
          - merge_maps(cache, ParseJSON(body), "insert") where IsMatch(body, "^\\{")
          # set message
          - set(body, cache["message"]) where cache["message"] != nil

          # set trace/span id
          - set(trace_id.string, cache["trace_id"]) where cache["trace_id"] != nil
          - set(span_id.string, cache["span_id"]) where cache["span_id"] != nil

          # set severity when available
          - set(severity_number, SEVERITY_NUMBER_INFO) where IsMatch(cache["level"], "(?i)info")
          - set(severity_number, SEVERITY_NUMBER_WARN) where IsMatch(cache["level"], "(?i)warn")
          - set(severity_number, SEVERITY_NUMBER_ERROR) where IsMatch(cache["level"], "(?i)err")
          - set(severity_number, SEVERITY_NUMBER_DEBUG) where IsMatch(cache["level"], "(?i)debug")
          - set(severity_number, SEVERITY_NUMBER_TRACE) where IsMatch(cache["level"], "(?i)trace")
          - set(severity_number, cache["severity_number"]) where cache["severity_number"] != nil

          # move log_record attributes to resource
          - set(resource.attributes["container_name"], attributes["container_name"])
          - set(resource.attributes["container_id"], attributes["container_id"])
          - delete_key(attributes, "container_id")
          - delete_key(attributes, "container_name")

          - delete_matching_keys(cache, "^(message|trace_id|span_id|severity_number)$")

          - merge_maps(attributes, cache, "insert")

  batch:
    timeout: 5s
    send_batch_size: 100000

exporters:
  prometheusremotewrite:
    endpoint: "${PROMETHEUS_ENDPOINT}"
    headers:
      Authorization: "${PROMETHEUS_PASSWORD}"
    remote_write_queue:
      enabled: true
    resource_to_telemetry_conversion:
      enabled: true
    timeout: 15s
    tls:
      insecure: true
      
  clickhouse:
    endpoint: "${CLICKHOUSE_ENDPOINT}"
    database: "otel_metrics"
    username: "default"
    password: "${CLICKHOUSE_PASSWORD}"
    timeout: 10s
    create_schema: true
    logs_table_name: otel_logs
    traces_table_name: otel_traces
    metrics_table_name: otel_metrics
    
service:
  telemetry:
    logs:
      level: "debug"
      
  pipelines:
    metrics:
      receivers: [prometheus]
      exporters: [prometheusremotewrite, clickhouse]
    logs:
      receivers: [otlp, fluentforward/tcp]
      processors: [batch, transform/firelens]
      exporters: [clickhouse]

and my task definition
{
  "family": "ENVIRONMENT_NAME-web",
  "taskRoleArn": "TASK_ROLE_ARN",
  "executionRoleArn": "EXECUTION_ROLE_ARN",
  "networkMode": "awsvpc",
  "requiresCompatibilities": ["FARGATE"],
  "cpu": "1024",
  "memory": "2048",
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "ENVIRONMENT_NAME-web",
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "containerPort": 3000,
          "hostPort": 3000,
          "protocol": "tcp"
        },
        {
          "containerPort": 9394,
          "hostPort": 9394,
          "protocol": "tcp"
        }
      ],
      "image": "",
      "essential": true,
      "command": [
        "bundle",
        "exec",
        "rails",
        "server",
        "-b",
        "0.0.0.0",
        "-p",
        "3000"
      ],
      "environment": [
        {
          "name": "ECS_SERVICE_NAME",
          "value": "web"
        }
      ],
      "logConfiguration": {
        "logDriver": "awsfirelens",
        "options": {
          "Name": "forward",
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": "24224",
          "require_ack_response": "true" 
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "otel-collector",
      "essential": true,
      "image": "xxx/prod-opentelemetry-collector:latest",
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "containerPort": 5568,
          "hostPort": 5568,
          "protocol": "tcp"
        },
        {
          "containerPort": 24225,
          "hostPort": 24225,
          "protocol": "tcp"
        },
        {
          "containerPort": 4318,
          "hostPort": 4318,
          "protocol": "tcp"
        },
        {
          "containerPort": 4317,
          "hostPort": 4317,
          "protocol": "tcp"
        },
        {
          "containerPort": 24284,
          "hostPort": 24284,
          "protocol": "tcp"
        }
      ],
      "environment": [
        {
          "name": "JOB_NAME",
          "value": "web"
        }
      ],
      "user": "0",
      "logConfiguration": {
        "logDriver": "awslogs",
        "options": {
          "awslogs-group": "/ENVIRONMENT_NAME/web-logs",
          "awslogs-region": "REGION_NAME",
          "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
        }
      }
    },
{
  "name": "fluent-bit",

      "portMappings": [
        {
          "containerPort": 24224,
          "hostPort": 24224,
          "protocol": "tcp"
        }
      ],
  "image": "xxxx/prod-fluent-bit:latest",
  "essential": true,
  "firelensConfiguration": {
    "type": "fluentbit",
    "options": {
      "enable-ecs-log-metadata": "true"
    }
  },
  "logConfiguration": {
    "logDriver": "awslogs",
    "options": {
      "awslogs-group": "/ENVIRONMENT_NAME/web-logs",
      "awslogs-region": "REGION_NAME",
      "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
    }
  }
}
  ]
}


fluent-bit logs
October 17, 2024 at 16:26 (UTC+2:00)
[2024/10/17 14:26:18] [ info] [output:null:null.0] worker #0 started
fluent-bit
October 17, 2024 at 16:26 (UTC+2:00)
[2024/10/17 14:26:18] [ info] [output:forward:forward.1] worker #0 started
fluent-bit
October 17, 2024 at 16:26 (UTC+2:00)
[2024/10/17 14:26:18] [ info] [input:tcp:tcp.0] listening on 127.0.0.1:8877
fluent-bit
October 17, 2024 at 16:26 (UTC+2:00)
[2024/10/17 14:26:18] [ info] [input:forward:forward.1] listening on unix:///var/run/fluent.sock
fluent-bit
October 17, 2024 at 16:26 (UTC+2:00)
[2024/10/17 14:26:18] [ info] [input:forward:forward.2] listening on 127.0.0.1:24224
fluent-bit
October 17, 2024 at 16:26 (UTC+2:00)
[2024/10/17 14:26:18] [ info] [sp] stream processor started
fluent-bit
October 17, 2024 at 16:26 (UTC+2:00)
[2024/10/17 14:26:18] [ info] [output:forward:forward.1] worker #1 started
fluent-bit
October 17, 2024 at 16:26 (UTC+2:00)
[2024/10/17 14:26:18] [ info] [fluent bit] version=1.9.10, commit=eba89f4660, pid=1
fluent-bit
October 17, 2024 at 16:26 (UTC+2:00)
[2024/10/17 14:26:18] [ info] [storage] version=1.4.0, type=memory-only, sync=normal, checksum=disabled, max_chunks_up=128
fluent-bit
October 17, 2024 at 16:26 (UTC+2:00)
[2024/10/17 14:26:18] [ info] [cmetrics] version=0.3.7
fluent-bit
October 17, 2024 at 16:26 (UTC+2:00)
* Copyright (C) 2015-2022 The Fluent Bit Authors
fluent-bit
October 17, 2024 at 16:26 (UTC+2:00)
* Fluent Bit is a CNCF sub-project under the umbrella of Fluentd
fluent-bit
October 17, 2024 at 16:26 (UTC+2:00)
* https://fluentbit.io
fluent-bit
October 17, 2024 at 16:26 (UTC+2:00)
Fluent Bit v1.9.10
fluent-bit


actually, i see in logs
October 17, 2024 at 16:34 (UTC+2:00)
[2024/10/17 14:34:41] [ warn] [input:forward:forward.2] fd=66 incoming data exceed limit (6144000 bytes)
fluent-bit
October 17, 2024 at 16:34 (UTC+2:00)
[2024/10/17 14:34:41] [error] [output:forward:forward.1] cannot get ack
fluent-bit
October 17, 2024 at 16:34 (UTC+2:00)
[2024/10/17 14:34:41] [ warn] [engine] failed to flush chunk '1-1729175681.8912538.flb', retry in 8 seconds: task_id=0, input=forward.2 > output=forward.1 (out_id=1)```

currently, i see in logs 

October 17, 2024 at 16:34 (UTC+2:00)
[2024/10/17 14:34:41] [ warn] [input:forward:forward.2] fd=66 incoming data exceed limit (6144000 bytes)
fluent-bit
October 17, 2024 at 16:34 (UTC+2:00)
[2024/10/17 14:34:41] [error] [output:forward:forward.1] cannot get ack
fluent-bit
October 17, 2024 at 16:34 (UTC+2:00)
[2024/10/17 14:34:41] [ warn] [engine] failed to flush chunk '1-1729175681.8912538.flb', retry in 8 seconds: task_id=0, input=forward.2 > output=forward.1 (out_id=1)```

